# Custom listview selector / drawable dimensions?

Tags: android, listview, drawable

Is there any way I can set my listview selector to a custom drawable that only occupies a portion of the item view? I have made a drawable rectangle and set it as the selector, but I'm having a difficult time getting it to size properly. The picture shows what I have now (1) and the desired effect (2). [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - initially decided to just set the selector as a drawable that only shows a border on one side, and messed around with insets to no avail (for some reason the top and bottom were not working properly). So I just made a layer list and offset the top layer to the right by a few dp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="5dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```